# Difference between import {module} and import module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have seen the following two variations for importing code from another module in ES6:

```
import {module}  from "./Module"
```

and

```
import module from "./Module"
```

where `module` is a ES6 class defined in the file

> Module.js

What is the difference between the two import statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is the way it is exported.

```
export default const myModule = {}
```

Basically it says "this is the default export". You import this with

```
import myModule from 'module'
```

The other way is that multiple entry points can be exported like this:

```
export const myModule1 = {}
export const myModule2 = {}
```

You import these with

```
import {myModule1, myModule2} from 'module'
```

and if both a default and named entry points are exported you can do this:

```
import myModule, {myModule1, myModule2} from 'module'
```

It does not seem completely logical, usually the package author should explain how their module should be imported. If you are the author, this will help you

Comment: Comma missing in last import

Answer (score 1):

In the first case

```
import {module}  from "./Module"
```

you are importing single export from a module and inserts 'module' in the current scope. In `Module.js` file you have to have named exports:

```
export { module, module2 };
```

Please notice there are two named exports, but you are importing only one.

In second example you are importing default export:

```
import module from "./Module"
```

and in your `Module.js` file export can look like this:

export default module3;

Notice that you can import your default under different name.